# How to unfold a group that is a direct member of another group into its included users in Azure AD?

Tags: active-directory, azure

> How to unfold a group that is a direct member of another group into its included users in Azure AD?

I'm trying to use a group to configure SSO for a set of users. However, it only works when users are directly included (referred to as *direct members*).

How can I unfold the "lddprobff" group into its included users for SSO to work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no functionality in the UI to do this, your best bet is to use PowerShell to get the group, list the members and add them to the other group.

Comment: That's pity :( It's a nightmare to administrate, if you want to embed the same group within a large number of other groups. How is this normally tackled?

Comment: You can either automate it with a script, or you can look at something like SCIM for auto provisioning https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/sync-scim